# Как правильно использовать do/while Си?

Tags: c, for, while

У меня стоит задача - переделать данный код с использованием do/while.То есть просто конвертировать из for в do/while.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
#include <conio.h> 
  
#include <math.h> 
  
void main() 
  
{ 
  
int i=1,j,n=1,K,T; 
float S,P; 
K=1;S=0; 
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){ 
     
    {     K=K*2;      P=1; 
     
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++) { 
                P=P*(j+cos(j));   } 
     
       S=S+((2*i*(sin(i+1)))/P); 
       printf ("\n\nРезультат=%f",S); 
      } 
  
} 
     
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=1;
do {
    . . .
    j = 1;
    do {
        . . .
        j++;
    } while (j<=i)
    . . .
    i++
} while (i<=5)
```